# Workstation 10 unity, control guest program icon in host taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, vmware-unity

On VmWare Workstation 10, I'm running Windows 7 guest operating system with MS Outlook 2010 inside Windows 7 host operating system. The purpose is to alow for 2 instances of Outlook to run in parallel. VmWare runs in unity mode.

However I found that the task bar icon in the host can not be changed, it always reverts to Outlooks default icon, even if the icon is changed in the guest. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run multiple instances of Outlook 2010 anyway. Is there a particular reason you've decided to opt for virtualized, Unity-ed software rather than just running another instance of Outlook?

Comment: Yes, to my knowledge it is actually not possible to run multiple instances, rather multiple accounts are recommended. But in this use case, this is not wanted.

Comment: Oh, you mean multiple instances of Outlook with separate profiles?

Comment: yes that is what I mean